# Weird loop in hashed matrix multiplication

Tags: c, loops, matrix, hash, matrix-multiplication

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef double myfloat;
typedef unsigned int myindex;

// always row, colum
// row major
myindex rm(int i, int m, int N, int M) {return i*M + m; }
// column major
myindex cm(int i, int m, int N, int M) {return m*N + i; }

void MxMnaive(int N, int M, int K, myfloat *A, myfloat *B, myfloat *C) {
  // computes C += AB, C: N x M, A: N x K, B: K x M, all in row major layout
  int i,j,k;
  for(i=0; i< N; i++)
    for(j=0; j<M; j++)
      for(k=0; k<K; k++) 
        C[rm(i,j, N,M)] += A[rm(i,k, N,K)] * B[rm(k,j, K,M)];  
}


int x = 0;
int nextPR() {
  x =  (x+234532)*((x>> 5 )+12234);
  return x & 1023;
}

int hash(int a, int b) { return (a>>5 | a<<27)*(b+2352351);}
int main(int argc, char **argv){

  if( argc != 3 ) {
    printf("Usage: mult N seed\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  myindex N = atoi(argv[1]);
  x = atoi(argv[2]);

  myfloat *A = malloc( N*N*sizeof(myfloat));
  myfloat *B = malloc( N*N*sizeof(myfloat));
  myfloat *C = malloc( N*N*sizeof(myfloat));

  int i,j;

  if( A == NULL || B==NULL || C==NULL ) {
    printf("Could not allocate memory");
    exit(2);
  }

  for(int k=0;k<N/2+1;k++) {
    for(i=0; i< N; i++) {
      for(j=0; j<N; j++) {
        A[rm(i,j,N,N)] = nextPR();
        B[rm(i,j,N,N)] = nextPR();
        C[rm(i,j,N,N)] = 0;
      }
    }
    MxMnaive(N,N,N, A,B,C);
  }
  int h = atoi(argv[2]);
  for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
    for(int i=0; i< N*N; i++) {
      //    printf("%f ", C[i]);
      h = hash(h, (int) C[i]);
    }
  printf( "%d\n", h & 1023);
  return 0;
}
```

The above code is an exercise that we had in applied algorithm class. It is to compute the multiplication of two matrices. I asked my teacher but didn't really understand the answer, and am a bit embarrassed to keep asking the same question over and over, so I turn to SO for help.

The part I don't understand is the loops that surround the matrix initialization and the hashing:

```
for(int k=0;k<N/2+1;k++) {
    ...
}
```

and,

```
for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
```

First, why are we running the matrix initializations and the matrix multiplications N/2+1 times?

Secondly, why this magic value of k<3 when we hash the matrix C?

Thank you.

Comment: This is the reason why magic numbers must be avoided. Moreover comments in that part of code can help a lot.

Comment: It seems to only skip the first N^3 results of the pseudo random generator and then use the last evaluated C to generate 3N^2 hash values. Why it does it this way is beyond my understanding.